# When trying to pass a string directly to a function results in Segmentation error

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, c-strings, string-literals

When trying to pass a string directly to a function results in Segmentation error whereas copying in an array and running it works fine. I am having hard time understanding this cause of segmentation fault. I looked up related questions on this forum but still hard to understand.

I have written following code:

This works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * toLowerCase(char * str);

int main()
{
    char arr[] = "Hello World Tommy";

    printf("%s",toLowerCase(arr));

    return 0;
}


char * toLowerCase(char * str){

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if((str[i] >= 'A') && (str[i] <= 'Z'))
        {
            str[i] += 32;
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

This does not and results in Segmentation fault:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * toLowerCase(char * str);

int main()
{   
    printf("%s",toLowerCase("Hello World Tommy"));

    return 0;
}


char * toLowerCase(char * str){

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if((str[i] >= 'A') && (str[i] <= 'Z'))
        {
            str[i] += 32;
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Niether does this work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * toLowerCase(char * str);

int main()
{
    char *arr = "Hello World Tommy";

    printf("%s",toLowerCase(arr));

    return 0;
}


char * toLowerCase(char * str){


    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if((str[i] >= 'A') && (str[i] <= 'Z'))
        {
            str[i] += 32;
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: [What is the difference between char s\[\] and char \*s?](//stackoverflow.com/a/1704433)

Comment: Thanks Johnny for the help.

Comment: You have to allocate memory for the character array if you would like to modify it. `char arr[] = "Hello World Tommy";` creates an array with the appropriate length as an auto and fills it with the specified characters, kind of like if you said `int nums[] = {1,3,7,8}`,  the other methods don't allocate any memory in a variable like an auto or a global or anything, they just are a pointer, the actual characters are stored somewhere else that you are not supposed to modify (could be in read only memory)

Answer (score 2):

Character literals are immutable in C. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior.

From the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
>   elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to
>   modify such an array, the behavior is undefined**

These calls

```
printf("%s",toLowerCase("Hello World Tommy"));
```

and

```
char *arr = "Hello World Tommy";

printf("%s",toLowerCase(arr));
```

pass pointers to the first characters of string literals to the function  `toLowerCase`.

Pay attention to that in general this function definition

```
char * toLowerCase(char * str){

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if((str[i] >= 'A') && (str[i] <= 'Z'))
        {
            str[i] += 32;
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

is invalid. For example the function will not work with characters using the table EBCDIC.

Answer (score 1):

The real answer to your question is in the comments, (Summarized as *string literals are immutable*.)  In general, anytime the value passed into a function needs to change, it cannot be *immutable*, it cannot be `const` and the argument passed must be a pointer to (the address of) the variable intended to be changed.
The comments and other answers make the reasons why it doesn't work clear.  So, one way to make it *work*  with both `string literals` and `char *str` (without changing the prototype.) is to do something like this:

```
char * toLowerCase(char * str);

int main()
{   
    char *str = toLowerCase("Hello World Tommy");
    if(str)
    {
        printf("%s", str);
        free(str);
    }

    return 0;
}

//This method leaves the argument aloan, but creates
//a changeable copy that is modified and returned.
//But - The memory created here must be freed in the calling function!
char * toLowerCase(char * str){

    int i, len;

    len = strlen(str);
    char *newstr = calloc(len + 1, 1);
    strcpy(newstr, str);

    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if((newstr[i] >= 'A') && (newstr[i] <= 'Z'))
        {
            newstr[i] += 32;
        }
    }
    newstr[i] = 0;
    return newstr;
}
```

The upside is it works with both:

```
char *str = "this is a string literal";
char str[] = {"this is a mutable string"};
```

The down side is the extra code, and dynamic memory allocation/freeing.